RxJS observable that fires if it's the first of a kind OR a certain time went by
Hey RxJS pros out there,
I have a stream that procs multiple times a second. Now I want an observer that procs if it's the first of a kind OR a certain time went by after the last proc. I want to achieve this with pure RxJS without additional "helper variables".
Scenario:
const list = ["foo", "foo", "bar", "foo",
              "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo",
              "foo", "foo", "bar", "foo"];

// in real world obs$ drops "foo" and "bar" randomly infinite times
const obs$ = timer(0, 100).pipe(take(12)); 

$obs
  .pipe(map((v, i)=>list[i]+"#"+i))
  .subscribe(console.log); 

Below are all the values fired by the observable. I want to catch the green ones (✅), and ignore the red ones (❌).
// ⬇
"foo#1"  // ✅ first of a kind
"foo#2"  // ❌
"bar#3"  // ✅ first of a kind
"foo#4"  // ✅ first of a kind
"foo#5"  // ❌
"foo#6"  // ❌
"foo#7"  // ❌
"foo#8"  // ❌
"foo#9"  // ✅ <-- I want this one too, because a certain time (0.5 seconds) went by
"foo#10" // ❌
"bar#11" // ✅ first of a kind
"foo#12" // ✅ first of a kind

So I want this output:
1#foo
3#bar
4#foo
9#foo
11#bar
12#foo

How?

You can use the scan operator to compute a "state" based on a prior state and the incoming emission.
In this case, our "state" will be an object with all the info needed to determine whether a given emission should be emitted or not.  We can provide an initial state that the scan function will use when handling the first emission. After that, it will use the value we return as the state.
Here's what we can use as the initial state:
{
  startTime: Date.now(),
  previousKind: '',
  shouldEmit: true,
  item: '',
}


startTime is used to determine if enough time has passed to force emitting.
previousKind is to keep track of the kind of item previously emitted, so we can determine if the current item is different from the previous.
shouldEmit is a boolean to indicate if this item should be emitted.
item is just the emitted item.

This info will be used inside our scan operator below to generate the new state and this is the same shape that will be emitted by the scan operator:
obs$.pipe(
  scan(/* generates state - details revealed later */),
  filter(state => state.shouldEmit),
  map(state => state.item)
).subscribe(
  item => console.log(`✅ ${item}`)
); 

You can see we apply our scan operation, then simply filter out items that are not marked as shouldEmit, then, we use map to emit the original item.

Here is the contents of the scan operator.
  scan((state, item) => {
    const kind = item.split('#')[0];
    const isFirstOfKind = kind !== state.previousKind;
    const durationExceeded = Date.now() - state.startTime > DURATION;
    const shouldEmit = isFirstOfKind || durationExceeded;

    return {
      startTime: shouldEmit ? Date.now() : state.startTime,
      previousKind: kind,
      shouldEmit,
      item,
    }
  }, {
    startTime: Date.now(),
    previousKind: '',
    shouldEmit: true,
    item: '',
  })

You can see we pass scan a function that receives the prior state and the current emission ('item').  With this info, we return a new state that will be emitted to operators downstream.  This state is also available the next time scan receives an emission.

Here is a StackBlitz demo.

It works like a charm! Puzzle solved. For me it has a downfall though, because of little twist I just forgot about while giving the "exercise". It's: I always need the last value. (Like in debounce). So basically: When I add an additional "foo" at the end of the array, I want that last "foo" too. I think your approach can't tackle that, because it makes decision based on the last value. Problem can be seen here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-78714425-xbwpm2?devtoolsheight=100&file=index.ts

This solution  with scan is much cleaner than mine. I have deleted my post. good job.

Maybe this solution will work for the additional requirement.  The idea is to create an observable for each item that will emit two values, one immediately, then one after DURATION has passed. If a new emission occurs before DURATION, then the second value will never emit.  I also added index as a unique property for each item, so we can use distinct to filter out items that have already been emitted. I don't have time to test or clean up, but this might work or at least point you in a helpful direction. :-)

I found another solution which as not as precise as yours but leaner and works for my real life scenario (https://stackoverflow.com/a/78719103/5708639). Thanks again wrapping your head around this!

After BizzyBob gave the correct answer I found something that feels more "native". It's not fullfilling the given requirement 100%, but it does the job for my real life scenario. So I want to share it.
obs$
  .pipe(
    groupBy((x) => x.split('#')[0]),
    mergeMap((group) =>
      group.pipe(
        throttleTime(500, undefined, { leading: false, trailing: true })
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe((item) => console.log(`✅ ${item}`));

throttleTime() always outputs a distincted value after some time (500ms), if at at least one value came into input in that timespan. Because I grouped values with groupBy, throttleTime() can count on that all input values are the same.
Here is the output:
✅ bar#3
✅ foo#5
✅ foo#10
✅ bar#11
✅ foo#12

As mentioned it's not matching the requirement, but still, it's working like debounceTime PLUS  "forcing piping every x seconds". That was what I needed.
Stackblitz
